# Fill null values with closest upper and lower non-null value element difference

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to achieve the following goal using `sql` in Snowflake?

**Original Table:**
Order | Value |
1   | 80 |
2   | null |
3   | null |
4   | 20 |

**Output table:**
Order | Value |
1   | 80 |
2   | 60 |
3   | 40 |
4   | 20 |

I understand this would requiere a fairly complex window operation and may be an overreach for standard `sql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus assume `order` is only a direction of the steps and not a linear mapping of the step size. Otherwise `rn` can be replace with `ov` to match the steps in your original order.

And it has no partitioning if you are running multiple data sets concurrently.

```
SELECT * 
    ,lead(v) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as nv
    ,lag(v) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as pv
    ,lead(nrn) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as nnrn
    ,lag(nrn) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as pnrn
    ,nvl(v, ((nv-pv)/(nnrn-pnrn)*(rn-pnrn))+pv) as value
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() over (order by ov) as rn
        ,nvl2(v,rn,null) as nrn
    FROM values
        (1,80),
        (2,null),
        (3,null),
        (4,20)
         t(ov, v)
)
order by ov;
```

gives:

| OV | V | RN | NRN | NV | PV | NNRN | PNRN | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 1 | 1 | 20 |  | 4 |  | 80 |
| 2 |  | 2 |  | 20 | 80 | 4 | 1 | 60 |
| 3 |  | 3 |  | 20 | 80 | 4 | 1 | 40 |
| 4 | 20 | 4 | 4 |  | 80 |  | 1 | 20 |

or if you want it to look tidy:

```
WITH data as (
    SELECT *   
    FROM values
        (1,80),
        (2,null),
        (3,null),
        (4,20),
        (5,null),
        (6,null),
        (7,11)
         t(ov, v)
)
SELECT ov, v, value 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
        ,lead(v) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as nv
        ,lag(v) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as pv
        ,lead(nrn) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as nnrn
        ,lag(nrn) ignore nulls over (order by ov) as pnrn
        ,nvl(v, ((nv-pv)/(nnrn-pnrn)*(rn-pnrn))+pv) as value
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,row_number() over (order by ov) as rn
            ,nvl2(v,rn,null) as nrn
        FROM data
    )
)
order by ov;
```

| OV | V | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 80 |
| 2 |  | 60 |
| 3 |  | 40 |
| 4 | 20 | 20 |
| 5 |  | 17 |
| 6 |  | 14 |
| 7 | 11 | 11 |

Comment: Thanks! I had found a similar approach but with an additional step. Partitioning over a key makes this example usable in my more complex scenario.

Comment: Yes partioning is almost always required. And i would normally expand the data to show this. But this eas complex enough without  add ing the extra detail. Glad to hear you eorked that bit out.